# How to update the Quartz Job trigger cron time directly from DB in DotNet Quartz

Tags: .net-core, cron, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I'm using dot net quartz 3.1 scheduler in my application. Everything is going good.

I had already created the new quartz job with it triggers and its working fine. But, i need to change the trigger time of the job alone directly from DB.

So, i try to update the cron values(Cron_Expression column) from **QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS** Table. After updating the new cron values directly my job was not triggered.

Can anyone please help me to update cron trigger time directly into Quartz scheduler related tables in My DB?

Please find the query i tried,

```
update [dbo].[QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS] set cron_expression = '0 5 6,7,8 * * ?' where trigger_name ='xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Note: I know, we can directly create new job and trigger instead of updating the cron value directly from DB. But my requirement is need to update the trigger time alone for the existing job.

DB server : SqlServer

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't update the Quartz tables directly using SQL. Use the Quartz API to update the schedule, though there is no way to do this without creating a new trigger (but not a new job).

This is our C# Code:

```js
    var triggerKey = new TriggerKey(triggerName, triggerGroup);
    var trigger = await _scheduler.GetTrigger(triggerKey);
    
    var builder = trigger.GetTriggerBuilder();
    var newTrigger = (CronTriggerImpl)builder.Build();
    newTrigger.CronExpressionString = "0 5 6,7,8 * * ?";
    await _scheduler.RescheduleJob(trigger.Key, newTrigger);
```

Note- you can update other properties of the trigger as needed but I left those out to keep the snippet short.

Comment: So you have a global `_scheduler` which is always in memory?  Cauz, you didn't create a new scheduler.  @todji

Comment: Yes, we do. Though it's not necessary for just doing updates to job schedules. But isn't that the point? You want the scheduler always open in a background service so it can trigger jobs as needed.